# Adding CSS using function in PHP

Tags: php, css, relative-path

I was try to add `CSS` file to my `html` file using statistic function like this:

```
      public static function addCSS($file){
         $cssPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'new'. 
         DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'css/'.$file;
           return file_exists($cssPath) ? "
   <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$cssPath\" type=\"text/css\" 
    media=\"screen\" charset=\"utf-8\" />
    " : "CSS File not found";
        }
```

but it doesn't work as i expected. i want it to produce the CSSPath like "http:localhost/new/css/admin.css when I'm called using 
`General::addCSS('admin.css');` but all i got is address like this which make me fail to include: C:/xampp/htdocs\new\css/admin.css. how can i fix this addressing?

Comment: "http:localhost\new\css\admin.css" Change this path like http://localhost/new/css/admin.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using xampp, so the document root path will be from that "Server". Thats why the path is wrong. you will need to exclusively specify what path you want, until you move to your server.

Also, if you are using a shared hosting plan, document root will not work most of the time. Set up a Constant with the server root path so that you can use it just like you use DOCUMENT_ROOT.

```
     //Create root path
     define('ROOT', 'something/anotherthing/public_html');

     public static function addCSS($file){
     //use root path everywhere instead of document_root
     $cssPath = ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'new'. 
     DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'css/'.$file;
       return file_exists($cssPath) ? "
     <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$cssPath\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\" charset=\"utf-8\" />
     " : "CSS File not found";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, returns just that, a path to a directory and not a URL. If you want the URL to your site, try using:

```
"http://{$HTTP_HOST}{$REQUEST_URI}"
```

So, in your case it will be:

```
$REQUEST_URI= 'css/admin.css'

$cssPath = "http://{$HTTP_HOST}{$REQUEST_URI}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for `$cssPath` because it will be a system filepath, you need a url. If you really want to implement this feature this way try:

```
public static function addCSS( $file ){
    $css_dir =  DS . 'new'. DS . 'css'. DS;
    $css_file = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $css_dir . $file;
    $css_file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $css_dir . $file;
    return file_exists( $css_file_path ) ? '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$css_file.'" type="text/css" media="screen" />' : false;
}
```

My advice however is to reconsider your approach to the problem.

Comment: your script make adressing like this http://localhost/New/localhost/new/css/admin.css

Answer (score 0):

`DOCUMENT_ROOT` will return simply the document path  , But to include css you need an absolute or relative urls.You can try with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

```
public static function addCSS( $file ){
    $css_dir =  DS . 'new'. DS . 'css'. DS;
    $css_file = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $css_dir . $file;
    $css_file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $css_dir . $file;
    return file_exists( $css_file_path ) ? '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$css_file.'" type="text/css" media="screen" />' : false;
}
```

Comment: Also you can use relative urls by setting a base html tag in your header:

<base href="http://$your_host/" /> ( $your_host  can be localhost, localhost/yourProject, yourwebsite.com, etc. build a function to deduce it)

Then use relative urls for your links and assets...
For your css it would be something like $css_file = 'css/styles.css''

Comment: @ris your script addressing it seem only work on chrome, when i run on firefox it can't run. the address become http://localhost\new\css\admin.css